# How do I ask a Windows::Forms::GroupBox to resize?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, resize

I have a `Windos::Forms::GroupBox` which contains a `Windows::Forms::ListView`. When I add items, I add items to the `ListView` I tell it to resize but how do I do the same for it's parent `GroupBox`?

**[edit]** This is my custom resizing list control:

```
ResizingListView::ResizingListView(void)
{

}

void ResizingListView::ResizeVerticallyToItems(void)
{
    // Work out the height of the header
    int headerHeight = 0;
    int itemsHeight = 0;
    if( this->Items->Count == 0 )
    {
        // If no items exist, add one so we can work out how big the header is
        Items->Add("");
        headerHeight = GetHeaderSize();
        this->Items->Clear();
        itemsHeight = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        headerHeight = GetHeaderSize();
        itemsHeight = this->Items->Count*this->Items[0]->Bounds.Height;
    }

    // Work out the overall height and resize to it
    System::Drawing::Size sz = this->Size;
    int borderSize = 0;
    if( this->BorderStyle != System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None )
    {
        borderSize = 2;
    }
    sz.Height = headerHeight+itemsHeight+borderSize;
    this->Size = sz;
}

int ResizingListView::GetHeaderSize(void)
{
    return Items[0]->Bounds.Top;
}

void ResizingListView::OnResize(System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if( this->Scrollable == false )
    {
        ResizeVerticallyToItems();
    }
}
```

So when I finish aadding items I call `ResizeVerticallyToItems()` which resizes the control without any problems. The parent `GroupBox` has some padding though which disappears when my list resizes. So my thoughts were that I needed to ask the parent `GroupBox` to resize.

This is the group box's initialisation:

```
this->grpMyStatus->AutoSize = true;
this->grpMyStatus->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), 
    static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)));
this->grpMyStatus->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Stretch;
this->grpMyStatus->Controls->Add(this->lstMyStatus);
this->grpMyStatus->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Top;
this->grpMyStatus->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, 
    System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
this->grpMyStatus->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::SkyBlue;
this->grpMyStatus->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 166);
this->grpMyStatus->Name = L"grpMyStatus";
this->grpMyStatus->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3, 3, 3, 20);
this->grpMyStatus->Size = System::Drawing::Size(270, 92);
this->grpMyStatus->TabIndex = 5;
this->grpMyStatus->TabStop = false;
this->grpMyStatus->Text = L"My Status";
```

...and this is the child list's initialisation:

```
this->lstMyStatus->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), 
    static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)));
this->lstMyStatus->BorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None;
this->lstMyStatus->Columns->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ColumnHeader^  >(1) {this->columnHeader6});
this->lstMyStatus->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Top;
this->lstMyStatus->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
    static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
this->lstMyStatus->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(224)), 
    static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(224)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(224)));
this->lstMyStatus->HeaderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ColumnHeaderStyle::None;
this->lstMyStatus->HideSelection = false;
this->lstMyStatus->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^  >(3) {listViewItem3, 
    listViewItem4, listViewItem21});
this->lstMyStatus->LabelWrap = false;
this->lstMyStatus->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 18);
this->lstMyStatus->Name = L"lstMyStatus";
this->lstMyStatus->RightToLeft = System::Windows::Forms::RightToLeft::Yes;
this->lstMyStatus->RightToLeftLayout = true;
this->lstMyStatus->Scrollable = false;
this->lstMyStatus->ShowGroups = false;
this->lstMyStatus->ShowItemToolTips = true;
this->lstMyStatus->Size = System::Drawing::Size(264, 54);
this->lstMyStatus->SmallImageList = this->imgLights;
this->lstMyStatus->TabIndex = 18;
this->lstMyStatus->UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this->lstMyStatus->View = System::Windows::Forms::View::Details;
this->lstMyStatus->SelectedIndexChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Status::lstMyStatus_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of code? What resizing strategies do the components have (GrowAndShrink, etc.), what's the layout, how do you tell it to resize? Do you call PerformLayout()?

Comment: PerformLayout (on the group box) got it :) If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's automatic when you set the GroupBox' AutoSize property to True, it will grow as needed to fit the ListView.  This isn't very common in most typical layouts since that will makes it liable to overlap some other control or grow beyond the form edges.

Comment: We have a load of status information coming back from some hardware and depending on what extra devices are plugged in, there will be more or less information available. Hence the need for a resizing layout.

Comment: Well, don't underestimate a scrollbar :)  But it sounds to me that you'll need to make the form auto-sizing as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoSize` to `true` for the GroupBox

Good luck.